# Subquery returned more than 1 value, error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm getting the following error message;

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

The section of code I'm having problems with, is in my select statement;

```
    ,(SELECT COUNT(sch.startdate)
      FROM #test AS sch
      WHERE L.Id = sch.id
      GROUP BY sch.id, sch.startdate
      HAVING sch.startdate >= L.T_Start AND sch.startdate <= @END) AS SC
```

Currently it works if the person only has one record in the test temp table, but falls apart when there are two. I know I could use Top 1 to limit it, but that's not what I want. `L` is from the main select statement.

Ok so the temp table has the following data:

```
ID  startdate
1   2014-10-02
1   2014-11-02
2   2014-11-02
```

With the TOP 1 in my code I get the results below:

```
ID ~Other Stuff~  SC
1  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~  1
2  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~  1
```

But what I want to be returned is:

```
ID ~Other Stuff~  SC
1  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~  2
2  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~  1
```

How can I modify my code to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: In order to get a good answer, you'll still need to show the "main" `from` clause, instead of just the subquery. Conceptually, you want to get rid of the `group by` in the subquery and use to `where` clause to essentially join it to the main query with a `where sch.id = main.id` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to count. It also appears (without additional information) that you can move the HAVING clause into the WHERE clause.

If you are trying to count rows from #test that match:

```
,(SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM #test AS sch
  WHERE L.Id = sch.id
  AND sch.startdate >= L.T_Start AND sch.startdate <= @END) AS SC
```

If you are trying to count unique startdate values:

```
,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT sch.startdate)
  FROM #test AS sch
  WHERE L.Id = sch.id
  AND sch.startdate >= L.T_Start AND sch.startdate <= @END) AS SC
```

If you are trying to count unique combinations of (id, startdate) then I think you need another level of query:

```
,(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
      SELECT sch.id, sch.startdate
      FROM #test AS sch
      WHERE L.Id = sch.id
      AND sch.startdate >= L.T_Start AND sch.startdate <= @END
      GROUP BY sch.id, sch.startdate) 
    AS X) AS SC
```

See [COUNT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `sch.startdate` from the GROUP BY.   You want to count the StartDates, not Group By them.

Comment: I would think that it is the whole GROUP BY that should be removed because that would still be grouped by L.Id then.

Comment: It's true that you could remove the whole Group By and get the desired results, but I only mentioned startdate because that's the part that's causing the undesired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

HAVING is used to filter out groups where some condition is true of the entire group. Typically this is some aggregate from your grouping e.g.

```
HAVING sum(amount) > 10
```

You put

```
HAVING sch.startdate >= L.T_Start --...
```

which is pulling the L.T_start at the row level (since it's not an aggregate and not in your GROUP BY).

Depending on what you are trying to do, either

move that to the WHERE clause (to filter rows from the statement pre-grouping)

or

make it an aggregate (e.g. HAVING max(sch.startdate > L.T_start) etc.

or

group by that condition e.g. 
    group by
      -- ...,
      CASE when sch.startdate > L.T_start then 1 else 0 end
      -- ...
note that the last option could give you two groups so you should also include that CASE statement as a column in your select list to identify the difference.